# style table cells with data

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with some data values. I would like to add styles to change the cells with values to have a background color and to add a border color to the first cell.

Can I do it with CSS only or do I need to ad some jQuery code? I'm fine with either or both.

Here's a [demo of my table](http://jsfiddle.net/rkrHx/9/).

Comment: Presumably you're serving the page using some kind of server-side technology. If so, then you can just put appropriate styles on the cells serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jquery you could do (this adds a background color to all cell that have a value and adds a border to the first cell with a value but i can modify this as you want) EDIT - update to take account of the comment

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var firstDone = false;
    $(this).children('td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() != '') {
            if (!firstDone) {
                $(this).css('border', '2px solid yellow');
                firstDone = true;
            }
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rkrHx/11/

Comment: This is great. As far as the border goes I actually meant the first cell with data in each row. Sorry I was not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to add/remove CSS classes to the cells rather than style them directly with javascript. Try this one:

```
$("td").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text()) $(this).addClass('hasData');
});
$("tr").each(function(){
  $('td.hasData:first', this).addClass('firstCellwithData');
});
```

The second bit will only style the first cell with data, as I saw you clarify in the comments. Just add the styles to your CSS file for each of those two classes.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rkrHx/19/

Just come up with some better class names than what I used ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browsers you need to work, there is an [:empty](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/empty.html) pseudoclass for css that you can use to style empty elements differently.  According to this [compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t32), the minimum version of IE which supports this is 9. However, it seems to be supported by all recent versions of all other browsers.  You can use it like this.

```
td{
background-color: #F00;
}

td:empty {
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

The above will show all cells with data with a red (#F00) background, and all cells which are empty as having a white (#FFF) background.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border color through css but for setting background color based on data values you need to use javascript or jquery as below. You can use contains selector

```
$("table td:contains('datavalue')").css({backgroundColor:"yellow"});
```

Comment: In this case you would have to know what data to expect in the cell.

Comment: May I didnt understood the question correctly but thanks anyways